# Getting Sytax error using the While Loop in Python 3.3.2

Tags: loops, python-3.x, while-loop, syntax-error

Here is my code:

```
import random

secret = random.randint (1, 99)
guess = 0
tries = 0

print ("Ahoy!  I'm the Dread Pirate Roberts, and I have a secret!")
print ("It is a number from 1 to 99. I'll give you 6 tries. "

while tries < 6 and guess != secret:
guess = input ("What's yer guess? ")
    if guess < secret:
        print ("Too low, ye scurvy dog!")
    elif guess > secret:
        print ("Too High, landlubber!")
    tries = tries + 1
if (guess == secret):
    print ("AVAST! Ye got it! Found my secret, ye did it!"
else:
    print ("No more guesses! Better luck next time, matey!)
    print ("The secret number was"), secret
```

For some reason I am getting an invalid syntax on "while". I cannot seem to find out why as this used work for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis at the end of this line:

```
print ("It is a number from 1 to 99. I'll give you 6 tries. "
                                                             ^
```

This line isn't indented properly:

```
while tries < 6 and guess != secret:
guess = input ("What's yer guess? ")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`guess` will be a string, so you should convert it into an integer before treating it like one:

```
guess = int(input("What's yer guess? "))
```

Finally, this line is missing a closing double quote:

```
print ("No more guesses! Better luck next time, matey! )
                                                      ^
```

Comment: Ok, so thanks for being a second set of eyes. I greatly appreciate it. But when I run the program, I get the following output:>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Ahoy!  I'm the Dread Pirate Roberts, and I have a secret!
It is a number from 1 to 99. I'll give you 6 tries. 
What's yer guess? 15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mark Stewart\Desktop\Number.py", line 12, in <module>
    if guess < secret:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Comment: @user2472213: You never converted `guess` into an integer.

Comment: import random

    secret = random.randint (1, 99)guess = 0
tries = 0

print ("Ahoy!  I'm the Dread Pirate Roberts, and I have a secret!")
print ("It is a number from 1 to 99. I'll give you 6 tries. ")

while guess != secret and tries < 6:
    guess = int(input("What's yer guess? "))
    if guess < secret:
        print ("Too low, ye scurvy dog!")
    elif guess > secret:
        print ("Too High, landlubber!")
        tries = tries + 1
if (guess == secret):
    print ("AVAST! Ye got it! Found my secret, ye did it!")
else:
    print ("No more guesses! Better luck next time, matey!")

Comment: I'm trying to add the code but not used to this sit but I get the following error:>>>
Ahoy!  I'm the Dread Pirate Roberts, and I have a secret!
It is a number from 1 to 99. I'll give you 6 tries.
What's yer guess? 15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mark Stewart\Desktop\Number.py", line 12, in <module>
    if guess < secret:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Comment: guess = int(input("What's yer guess? "))   This is how I fixed it

Comment: @user2472213: You sure? `guess` is never a string, so your can't be getting that error with your current code.

Comment: while guess != secret and tries < 6:
    guess = int(input("What's yer guess? "))
    if guess < secret:
        print ("Too low, ye scurvy dog!")
    elif guess > secret:
        print ("Too High, landlubber!")
        tries = tries + 1
if (guess == secret):
    print ("AVAST! Ye got it! Found my secret, ye did it!")
else:
    print ("No more guesses! Better luck next time, matey!")
    print ("The secret number was"), secret

Comment: this is the error      >>>
Ahoy!  I'm the Dread Pirate Roberts, and I have a secret!
It is a number from 1 to 99. I'll give you 6 tries.
What's yer guess? 15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mark Stewart\Desktop\Number.py", line 12, in <module>
    if guess < secret:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()